# Array in main() changes in a function

Tags: arrays, c, variables

I have a program to sort some number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sort(int x[], int sizeArr){
    int i,j,temp=0;
    for(i=0;i<sizeArr;i++){
        for(j=0;j<sizeArr-1;j++){
            if(x[j]>x[j+1]){
                temp=x[j];
                x[j]=x[j+1];
                x[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int data[]={5,1,2,4,3};
    int sizeArr = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]);
    int i;
    printf("Data Array\n");
    for(i=0;i<sizeArr;i++){
        printf("Data no.%d= %d\n", i+1, data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    sort(data,sizeArr);
    printf("Data Array\n");
    for(i=0;i<sizeArr;i++){
        printf("Data no.%d= %d\n", i+1, data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Data Array
Data no.1= 5
Data no.2= 1
Data no.3= 2
Data no.4= 4
Data no.5= 3

Data Array
Data no.1= 1
Data no.2= 2
Data no.3= 3
Data no.4= 4
Data no.5= 5
```

And a similar program but without array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sort(int x){
    x=5;
}
int main()
{
    int data=3;
        printf("Data = %d\n", data);
    printf("\n");
    sort(data);
        printf("Data = %d\n", data);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Data = 3

Data = 3
```

What I want to ask is:

1. How a change in the **x[]** array in sort() can affect the **data[]** array in main()?
2. Why the **x** variable doesn't affect the **data** variable in the second program?
3. Is it possible to make **x[]** array independent from **data[]** array?
   I'm sorry if it's a dumb question and if my English is bad. Thanks.

Comment: The function declaration `void sort(int x[], int sizeArr)` is the same as `void sort(int *x, int sizeArr)`. That is, you pass a *pointer* to the first element of the array. You're not passing the array itself.

Comment: (and this is one of those weird C rules you just have to learn. No, there isn't any logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, `x` is a pointer to a chunk of memory. The same memory is being referred to inside and outside of the function, so if you alter the memory inside the function, you'll see the same changes outside the function.

For 2, `x` is a **copy** of the 3 passed into the function. `x` inside the function and `data` outside of the function are referring to different locations in memory. `x = 5` changes what's in the `x` memory location, but since that memory is just a copy of what `data` holds, it doesn't effect `data`.

For 3, you would need to make a copy of the array. This could be done manually by creating a second array then using a loop to copy each element to the new array, or you can use a function like [`memcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy).

---

A key to remember is whatever you pass into a function is copied. If you pass a pointer, the pointer is copied, but a copy of an address is still the same address when it's dereferenced by doing an operation like `x[j]`. If you pass in something like an integer, that integer is copied, so reassigning it will have no effect outside of the function.